# How to version(ise/ize) Android app properly?

Tags: android, gradle, versioning

I am working on an Android app and I have put it on playstore for beta testing. So I can officially test my app in different countries as I have friends overseas. So my question is that as My app is in beta testing, I have discovered some bugs in my app and I am fixing them one by one and uploading app for more tests. This is my firs official Android app and I have just opened my android app developer account couple days ago. So I am not so familiar with how android's app versioning works.

I know about .. version format. So right now, my app's major Version release is `1`. I have patched 2 bugs in it and posted on playstore so my friends can test it and send me feedback. To de this, I had to change `versionCode` in gradle file from `1` to `2`. Because playstore was not letting me upload patched apk. Now I have patched few more bugs in my app and if I go and upload to playstore, I will need to change `versionCode` in my gradle file from `2` to `3`. I know that playstore will display `versionName` in description but I don't know if I am doing right or not.

Lets say my app's current `versionName` is `1.0.2` as I have patched couple bugs in it. But my `versionCode` is `3`. So in future I get 10 more bugs, one after fixing each than my `versionCode` will be `13` and `versionName` will be `1.0.10`. And after that if I release minor version it will be `1.1.0` with `versionCode` = `14`.

After that I fix some more bugs and release major version so my app's `versionName` will be something like `2.0.0` with `versionCode` = `25`.

So am I doing it right or I need to change/learn something for it? I have searched about versioning and found some great tutorials about creating version.properties and all. But when I upload it to playstore, it keep saying me to change my `versionCode` from `1` or `2` to something else. And by something else I mean to increment.

Can anyone tell me what to do? Am I doing right or wrong?

Comment: You just need to increase the versionCode by at least 1 if you submit your app to the play store. The values are not necessarily related to each other

Comment: So you mean to say @0xDEADC0DE, it doesn't matter if my app's `versionCode` is `98` but my app's `versionName` is `1.2.5`. Is that right?

Comment: That's true. According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html), versionCode is only used to determine if there is a newer version of your app and it is not shown to users. The versionName is used to show to users

Comment: Okay @0xDEADC0DE. Thanks for helping me out. I was confused about it.

Comment: Make this your guide: http://semver.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things which are seen during versioning:

1. Version Code
2. Version Name

Now you can consider version code as your age, which is incremented whenever you celebrate your birthday, that is, version code is to be incremented, whenever you make a new build for Play store or you are sending the app via mail or drive. One reason for this is, in play store, it helps the google servers to differentiate between old and current release and in testing point of view you can filter the crashes in crashlytics based on this version code.

But when we talk about version name, its like your name, people might call you chhotu, chintu, etc. when you are young, they call you Viral when you are teen, they call you mr. Joshi when you are working, but it doesnt make a difference as its your age that exactly defines you.

In short, version code is to be changed after every build you make for testing, but version name is your choice. In general version name is changed when you make major bug fixes or UI changes. For small fixes you dont change version name in beta version. But when it is released completely, you can change the last digit of version name too after every release.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed for explaining this stuff to me. I was confused and so I asked here. :D

Answer (score 2):

`versionCode` can (should? personal choice really) be updated with each build, or at the start of each day you work on the code. A number that simply keeps increasing is all this needs to be. Start at `1` and keep going. Google Play Store requires an increase between updates.

`versionName` is for the Google Play Store or when you have built a stable version that is ready for testing with the intention of release. The format of this string is really up to you. Formats are often read like so:

- `1.2.3` : `1` major version, major changes, `2` minor version, minor
  changes, `3` bug fixes.
- `1.2` : `1` major version, major changes, `2` any changes.

You can (I think) even use a string like *UltraLight* or *MegaUpdate* for the `versionName` - it is up to you. It is used to differentiate between releases for the public.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me @Tiger. I got it now. :D

Comment: I would up vote your answer but I can't. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: @ViralJoshi : No problem at all.