# Android: updated Version Code of Android for Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-manifest

I have just forget the **VersionCode** of my application i don't know its version but i get **VersionName** through play store.

I just want to know that can i assign any **Greater integer value** because i know it is less than 5 or its mandatory to **increment it by 1**.

current manifest is   :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 android:versionCode="2"   // as i have forget this version
 android:versionName="1.0.1" >
```

i froget my ***vesrion code*** so want to Updated Manifest as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gwnt.image.blur"
    android:versionCode="5" //updated to a new code
    android:versionName="1.0.4"  //came to know from play store which is 1.0.3

    >
```

**Will the application will be updated at Play Store**

or Increment of 1 is mandatory.

Note: I am just Confirming because i have to update My application at ***Play Store***.

Comment: You can see the version code of your app in play store developer console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38865840/5471104 , see my answer for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to version(ise/ize) Android app properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865676/how-to-versionise-ize-android-app-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your `android:versionCode` in Developer console.

1. Login to developer account
2. Select APK from side menu
3. You get Production Tab with your version code, You also get version code from inProd row on same tab

Example :

[image]

Here, in PRODUCTION tab Versions 763,820 is version code

Answer (score 1):

You can increment with whatever you like. Have in mind that later you cant decrease that number, and if you put maximum integer there  you wont be able to update new version at all.
More info: [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html#appversioning)

Comment: Ok i will check it and get back to you